# Mocking json.dumps() method in Python unit tests

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

I am working on test case writing using Pytest and I need to mock a function which uses json.dumps() method.

I tried so many ways but somehow this method cannot be mocked.

I tried using decorator -

```
@mock.patch("json.dumps")
```

But this gives error.

```
TypeError: Object of type MagicMock is not JSON serializable
```

Just mocking json also does not work.

Any idea why only json library gives such problems? All my other patches are working fine.

How can I work around this problem?

Comment: Why mock it at all? In general you should mock what you don't own. What are you trying to test?

Comment: Point of clarity: That should read "...you _shouldn't_ mock what you don't own".

Comment: @Chris yes, thank you for clarifying, that's a pretty bad typo to have made!

Comment: Simple question.. what will you do if your function contain json.loads() within its function body? If you do not mock it, this function fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link helped me resolve the issue. (point 1)
https://www.godaddy.com/engineering/2018/09/04/python-mocking/

Rather than

```
@mock.patch("json.dumps")
```

I used

```
@mock.patch("<Modulename>.json")
```